# List of maps to list of values of each map

Tags: kotlin

I have a data structure like this[image]

It's a list of maps. How can I get a list of the values with "image" key from that?

From List<Map<K, V>> to List< V >.

**Update**

Right now I'm using something like this

```
val list = mutableListOf<String>()
listOfMaps.forEach {
    list.add(it.get("image"))
}
```

And it's even working. But I'm 100% sure there's another way to do it more clean.

Comment: This is called JSON parsing, you might want to give that a research. Plenty of different methods/libraries so it's really a matter of opinion.

Comment: Oh unless you already have a `List<Map<K, V>>`? I might have missed that.

Comment: @HenryTwist yes I do, now I just need to get a list of values from this maps (values by "image" key)

Comment: Ah I see. Well which part are you stuck on? Going through a list? Getting values from a map?

Comment: @HenryTwist I've updated my question with some code example. Maybe there's a cleaner way to do this using kotlin.collections? What should I use?

Comment: `val imagesList = listOfMaps.map { it["image"] }`

Comment: Yes the code from @Tenfour04 is the cleanest approach. If you take a look at the source for the `map` method, it is pretty much identical to what you've written.

Comment: If you're going to be doing any processing, I wouldn't store each recipe as a map at all; I'd write a `class Recipe` (e.g. a `data class`).  Then you get direct access to all the fields; everything's properly typed and self-describing, and you get fewer surprises at runtime.